# How to add two properties with same name so that we could be able to deserialize two different JSON formats?

Tags: c#, json, interface, javascriptserializer

I have to parse a JSON element; sometimes it will be a single object, sometimes an array of objects.  Instead of creating a separate class for each scenario, I wanted this in a single class.

```
 public name name { get; set; }
 public name[] name { get; set; }
```

I have referred to similar issues in Stack Overflow. In some cases, an interface is used to resolve it.

```
public class name : INames, INameLists
{
    nameval INames.name { get; set; }
    nameval[] INameLists.name { get; set; }
}
```

But this is not working for me.  The JSON element is not parsing, and I am getting an exception.

I want the condition such that, when an array of elements exists, it must parse to an array, otherwise to a single object.

Please help regarding this issue. I don't think this would be a duplicate issue. If so, then please let me know.

Comment: Do you tried to use attribute `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]`

Comment: Is the JSON itself out of your control? This sounds like a terrible use of JSON at the moment. You might want to go through an intermediate stage where you load the JSON dynamically (e.g. with LINQ to JSON in Json.NET), modify the names to be different, and then feed it through regular deserialization.

Comment: `public name name { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
  public name[] name1 { get; set; }`

I tried with this code. But still getting error.

Comment: I am de serialising through `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<class>` Its working fine for rest of the elements, only issue with this condition, If i give single name object then it wont parse name array object. If I give name array object then it wont parse single name object.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, its not dynamic case, If patient json data, then single name object, if doctor json data, then name array object. So for two scenario either I need to create separate class. but I am looking for single solution, instead of two classes. rest all json structure is same. only issue with name in both patient and doctor data.

Comment: It sounds like you *should* have two different classes here, possibly deriving from a common base class. It would have been useful to give that information in the question.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show examples of the two different JSON formats you are trying to deserialize?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue by using a custom [`JavaScriptConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) class to read the JSON element and decide what do with it: i.e., if the name is an array, populate one property on your class, or if it's a single object, populate a different property.
Of course, you cannot define a class that has two members of the same name without putting explicit interfaces on them like you showed in your question, so the properties will have to have different names.

I might define the class something like this:

```
public class NameObject
{
    public string[] Names { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (Names != null && Names.Length > 0) ? Names[0] : null; }
        set { Names = (value != null) ? new string[] { value } : null; }
    }
}
```

You can see here that the `Names` property always holds the real data, and the `Name` property is just a convenience for when there is only a single name.

Here is how I might write the converter:

```
public class NameObjectConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new Type[] { typeof(NameObject) }; }
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        NameObject nameObj = new NameObject();
        string singleName = GetValue<string>(dictionary, "name");
        if (singleName != null)
        {
            nameObj.Name = singleName;
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList arrayList = GetValue<ArrayList>(dictionary, "name");
            nameObj.Names = (arrayList != null) ? arrayList.Cast<string>().ToArray() : null;
        }
        return nameObj;
    }

    private T GetValue<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dict, string key)
    {
        object value = null;
        dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        return value != null && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()) ? (T)value : default(T);
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        NameObject nameObj = (NameObject)obj;
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (nameObj.Names != null && nameObj.Names.Length == 1)
        {
            dict.Add("name", nameObj.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add("name", nameObj.Names);
        }
        return dict;
    }
}
```

To use the converter, you must register it with the `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new List<JavaScriptConverter> { new NameObjectConverter() });
```

Here is a demo showing the converter in action with both JSON formats.  (I had to make up some fake JSON here since you did not mention what the actual JSON looks like in your question.)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
          ""doctor"": {
            ""name"": ""Dr. Herbert Q. Cunningham III""
          },
          ""patients"": {
            ""name"": [
              ""Joe Schmoe"",
              ""John Doe"",
              ""Steve Smith""
            ]
          }
        }";

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters(new List<JavaScriptConverter> { new NameObjectConverter() });
        MedicalData data = serializer.Deserialize<MedicalData>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("Doctor's name: " + data.Doctor.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Patients' names: ");
        foreach (string name in data.Patients.Names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  " + name);
        }
    }
}

public class MedicalData
{
    public NameObject Doctor { get; set; }
    public NameObject Patients { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Doctor's name: Dr. Herbert Q. Cunningham III
Patients' names:
  Joe Schmoe
  John Doe
  Steve Smith
```

Comment: very nice explanation. It helped me to resolve my issue.